# How to replace JS file with mitmproxy/mitmdump

Tags: mitmproxy

I am trying to use mitmdump to replace a JS file being requested by the server with my own JS file. I am not able to find anything in the docs regarding this, especially for the version that I'm using, i.e., 4.0.4.

What I tried was - `mitmdump --listen-port 8888 --replacements :~q:https://static.examimg.com/repojs/jpAllJsFuncs_v128.js:/home/akshansh/Projects/repo/web/js/jpAllJsFuncs_v129.js`

(Here I wanted to replace `https://static.examimg.com/repojs/jpAllJsFuncs_v128.js` file with `/home/akshansh/Projects/repo/web/js/jpAllJsFuncs_v129.js` which is present on my local machine.)

The above didn't seem to work. Also, the separator according to documents is `:` and I have `:` in the part I want to replace as well, how will I go around it? I wasn't able to find much in the docs. `--replace-from-file` is another option, which is now deprecated in the newer versions, for which I was not able to find the docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I use script that is launched together with mitmproxy:

```py
from mitmproxy import http

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.url == 'https://static.examimg.com/repojs/jpAllJsFuncs_v128.js':
        flow.request.url = '/home/akshansh/Projects/repo/web/js/jpAllJsFuncs_v129.js'
```